# Retrieving all documents of all collections from a database in MongoDB with PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a MongodDB database (mydbase) with different collections in it (coll1, coll2, coll3). I want to collect all documents of all collections in a structure of list (=database) of lists (=collections) of dicts (documents) with PyMongo. I tried the following:

```
[list(db.coll.find({})) for coll in db.collection_names()]
```

but it returns a list of empty lists. Which is kind of a weird, because if I query only one collection in a similar way:

```
list(db.coll1.find({}))
```

that gives a populated list as hoped for. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 4):

```
test = [ list(db[coll].find({})) for coll in db.collection_names() ]
```

`coll` is a variable, so we need to use `db[coll]` instead of `db.coll`

for example, for a db with a collection named `'knights'`

```
db.knights.find_one({}) # correctly from 'knights'
n = 'knights'
db.n.find_one({}) # get one document from 'n'
db[n].find_one({}) # correctly from 'knights'
db['n'].find_one({}) # from 'n' again
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
[[record for record in db[collection_name].find({})] for collection_name in db.collection_names()]
```

I would read this in the following way:

```
[something for collection_name in db.collection_names()]
```

We use `db.collection_names()` to obtain an iterable representing the names of the collections in our db.

We then iterate over that iterable, putting the current collection name in the variable `collection_name`. With that `collection_name` variable we do `something`.

This will form the outer list of your desired outcome.

Now, let's address the inner lists.

```
[record for record in db[collection_name].find({})]
```

First, let's identify the iterable. That is, `db[collection_name].find({})`. It's the combination of the two, `db[collection_name]` to access the collection and `.find({})` to get an iterable.

With the `collection_name` variable, from the outer list, we access the current collection. We can think of `db[collection_name]` as the current collection we are extracting records from.

From that collection, we find all records, `.find({})` and form a list with them.

Also, keep in mind, you are loading everything in memory. Depending on the size of your data base, this may not be a very good idea!